# SQL Server stored procedure check condition and update/insert

Tags: sql-server

I have one query like below, I can have better query than this, or is it properly coded? Any suggestion will be helpful for me.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[TransferStockFromWarehouse]
    @ItemCode varchar(200) = NULL,
    @ToWarehouse varchar(150) = NULL,
    @FromWarehouse varchar(150) = NULL,
    @Qty decimal = NULL
AS
    DECLARE @RealPrice decimal(18,2) = NULL
    SET @RealPrice = (SELECT Price 
                      FROM StockInWarehouse 
                      WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode 
                        AND WarehouseName = @ToWarehouse)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT ItemCode 
               FROM StockInWarehouse
               WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode 
                 AND WarehouseName = @ToWarehouse) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE StockInWarehouse  
        SET Qty = Qty + @Qty 
        WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode 
          AND WarehouseName = @ToWarehouse
    END
    ELSE IF (@RealPrice > 0) OR (@RealPrice IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO StockInWarehouse(ItemCode, ItemName, WarehouseName, Price, Qty)
        VALUES (@ItemCode, 
                (SELECT ItemName 
                 FROM ItemMaster 
                 WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode), @ToWarehouse,
                (SELECT Price 
                 FROM StockInWarehouse 
                 WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode AND WarehouseName = @FromWarehouse), @Qty)
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO StockInWarehouse(ItemCode, ItemName, WarehouseName, Price, Qty)
        VALUES (@ItemCode,
                (SELECT ItemName 
                 FROM ItemMaster 
                 WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode),
                @ToWarehouse,
                (SELECT Price 
                 FROM StockInWarehouse 
                 WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode AND WarehouseName = @FromWarehouse),
                @Qty)
    END
BEGIN
    UPDATE StockInWarehouse 
    SET Qty = Qty - @Qty
    WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode AND WarehouseName = @FromWarehouse
END
```

And sometimes it is not adding to Towarehouse quantity but same time deducted from fromwarehouse. Not all the time it is happening .

Comment: if it's working the way you want it to work, then it's fine, the only thing to minimize in stored procedure is using join, doing a nested SELECT is better than using joins, nested SELECT statements will make execution faster.

Comment: yea i cannot say it is working properly, feels somewhere i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the logic is regarding @Qty - but from a quick overview - this seems like all that it's doing:

```
    ALTER Procedure [dbo].[TransferStockFromWarehouse]
        @ItemCode varchar(200) = NULL,
        @ToWarehouse varchar(150) = NULL,
        @FromWarehouse varchar(150) = NULL,
        @Qty decimal = NULL
    AS
        IF EXISTS (SELECT ItemCode 
                   FROM StockInWarehouse
                   WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode 
                     AND WarehouseName = @ToWarehouse) 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE StockInWarehouse  
            SET Qty = Qty + @Qty 
            WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode 
              AND WarehouseName = @ToWarehouse
        END
            INSERT INTO StockInWarehouse(ItemCode, ItemName, WarehouseName, Price, Qty)
            VALUES (@ItemCode, 
                    (SELECT ItemName 
                     FROM ItemMaster 
                     WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode), @ToWarehouse,
                    (SELECT Price 
                     FROM StockInWarehouse 
                     WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode AND WarehouseName = @FromWarehouse), @Qty)
        END
BEGIN
    UPDATE StockInWarehouse 
    SET Qty = Qty - @Qty
    WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode AND WarehouseName = @FromWarehouse
END
```

RealPrice looks to not be used at all, making one of the IF's pointless.
Depending on indexes etc, I'd also consider making the INSERT into a JOIN instead of two selects.

Comment: that real price i mention there , if there is any price different between the store , it will take higher price only. i forget remove it from the code. now it is not applicable in this case.